# Как правильно писать библиотеку?

Tags: javascript

Пишу скрипт показа сообщения
.Файл `notify.js`:

```
;(function(){
    function Notify(titleText, messageText) {

        var notify = document.createElement("div");
        notify.className = "notify";
        var title = document.createElement("div");
        title.className = "notify title";
        title.innerHTML = titleText;
        var message = document.createElement("div");
        message.className = "notify message";
        message.innerHTML = messageText;

        notify.appendChild(title);
        notify.appendChild(message);
        function show(){
        document.body.appendChild(notify);
        }
  }
})();
```

При подключении скрипта в `index.html` и при вызове `Notify("title","message").show()` ошибка `Notify is not defined` и это понятно, но как по-другому писать, чтобы не было конфликтов с локальными скриптами?
Много ошибок допускаю, скажите, какие? Как правильно организовать код, писать библиотеку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас код локально создался и... умер, т. к. при завершении функции, её окружение уничтожается. Исключение - замыкание (например, ссылка на какие-то данные сохраняется и после завершения работы).

```js
// В параметрах передаём модуль и this (глобальный объект, не обязательно window)
(function(myModule, global){
  // Если есть система зависимостей AMD, добавляем модуль туда
  if(typeof define === "function" && define.amd)
 define("logger", [], () => myModule());

  // Если же это RequireJS, не будем идти против воли Творца :)
  else if(typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports)
    module.exports = myModule();
  
  // Если систем сборки нет, значит экспортируем в глобальный объект
  else
    global['logger'] = myModule();
}(function(){
  let myModule = _ => console.info(`Вывод '${_}' через модуль`);
  
  return myModule;
}, this));

// Сработает 3-я ветка экспорта
logger('Test');
```

Но стандарт устанавливает более интересную конструкцию для модулей, рекомендую [с ней ознакомится](http://frontender.info/es6-modules/).

Answer (score 1):

`Notify` у вас определён в области видимости внутри кложуры, его не видно снаружи. В вашем случае может подойти [паттерн модуль](http://largescalejs.ru/module-pattern/), тогда из функции возвращается объект.

Но вообще, сейчас в ECMAScript есть [стандарт модулей](https://learn.javascript.ru/modules). Это будет работать, если использовать что-то вроде [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Также можно использовать [CommonJS require](https://habrahabr.ru/post/181536/).